# select all patches at distance x from turtle

Tags: distance, netlogo, patch

I want to select all the patches at a randomly-generated distance eps from all turtles in a simulation and reset their color to yellow. This essentially draws a circle of patches around each turtle in the simulation. I have tried a few different options without success. Through perusing this forum I found some code that looks promising but still has some issues (posted here). I appreciate any suggestions for tweaking this code or using something else to solve this problem.

```
let eps2 eps
foreach [ eps2 ]
  [
      ask patches with 
  [
        distance myself > eps2 - 0.5 and
        distance myself < eps2 + 0.5
  ]
  [
    set pcolor yellow
  ]
]
```

eps is a turtle variable so using the let command allows me to circumvent using a turtle variable in patch context.

The foreach command does not recognize eps because it is not a constant, is there another command I could use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list` (see below), but ... why do you want a list?  As it stands, there is no need to use a list.

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 1
  ask turtle 0 [test]
end
to test
let eps2 10
foreach (list eps2 )  ;you can use `list`
  [
      ask patches with 
  [
        distance myself > eps2 - 0.5 and
        distance myself < eps2 + 0.5
  ]
  [
    set pcolor yellow
  ]
]
end
```

**Addendum:**

Since you indicate that you do not in fact need that list, you might try something along the lines of the following:

```
to test2
  ca
  crt 1
  ask encirclingPatches turtle 0 10 1 [set pcolor yellow]
end

to-report encirclingPatches [#t #dist #width]
  let _w2 (#width / 2)
  report patches with [
    distance #t > #dist - _w2
    and
    distance #t < #dist + _w2
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. To answer your question, I don't need to create a list of eps2. My main concern was selecting the patches that were within distance eps (+/- 0.5) of the turtle. I'd be open to other ways to code this section but this was the closest example I could find to what I'm trying to do. Previously I used in-radius but couldn't find a way to only select the perimeter points.